# How to combine two word documents into one via excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy-paste

Can you open two word documents from excel and copy over the contents from one to the other?

I have a macro that opens a word template that has bookmarks set up. It then takes this document and fills those bookmarks in based on data in excel I have told it to reference. It then saves this document in a separate file with a unique name.

What I now need it to do is open another word document and copy the whole contents to the bottom of the main document (the one with the bookmarks).

This then needs to loop through a list in excel repeating until it gets to the end.

My code I have so far is:

```
Sub LetterMerge()

Sheets("Letter Builder").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim TemplateNo As Integer
TemplateNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Letter Builder").Range("A9:A200"))

Dim filepath As String
filepath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim WordApp As Object
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim SyndNo As String
Dim Address1 As String
Dim CEO As String
Dim Recipient As String
Dim Cap As String



Dim I As Integer
For I = 9 To 200 ' TemplateNo 'SET NUMBER OF ROWS

'CYCLE THROUGH ROW POPULATING VARIABLES FOR LETTER
With ws
SyndNo = Cells(I, 47).Value
Address1 = Cells(I, 6).Value
CEO = Cells(I, 7).Value
Recipient = Cells(I, 8).Value
Cap = Cells(I, 34).Value


End With


'save letter
letter.SaveAs "File path where letter is saved" & SyndNo & "_Draft Letter.docx", wdFormatXMLDocument


letter.Bookmarks("SyndNo").Range.Text = SyndNo
letter.Bookmarks("CEO").Range.Text = CEO
letter.Bookmarks("Recipient").Range.Text = Recipient
letter.Bookmarks("Cap").Range.Text = Cap
    

'REPEAT
WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close
restart: Next I

WordApp.Application.Quit


Sheets("Details").Select

MsgBox "Letters have been produced."
```

Comment: Why are you not using Word’s MailMerge? It is designed for precisely this purpose.

Comment: Are *SyndNo ,Address1 , CEO , Recipient , Cap*  for the bookmarks' value in MS Word you said?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

*Cause the information you gave is incomplete and not clear enough, I can only imagine the simulation as follows:*

```vb
Sub LetterMerge()

    Sheets("Letter Builder").Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Rem Why do you need this TemplateNo ? It is not used in your code
    Dim TemplateNo As Integer
    TemplateNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Letter Builder").Range("A9:A200"))
    
    Rem Why do you need this filepath ? It is not used in your code
    Dim filepath As String
    filepath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim wordApp As Object, letter As Object, rng As Object, dSource As Object
    'Dim wordApp As Word.Application, letter As Word.Document, rng As Word.Range, dSource As Word.Document
    Dim filenameDoc As String, dSourceFullname As String
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wordApp.Visible = True
    'where are your Word Files ?
    
    
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False' This's already existed before
    
    Dim SyndNo As String
    Dim Address1 As String
    Dim CEO As String
    Dim Recipient As String
    Dim Cap As String
    
    Dim I As Integer
    For I = 9 To 200 ' TemplateNo 'SET NUMBER OF ROWS
        
        'CYCLE THROUGH ROW POPULATING VARIABLES FOR LETTER
        With ws
            SyndNo = Cells(I, 47).Value
            Address1 = Cells(I, 6).Value
            CEO = Cells(I, 7).Value
            Recipient = Cells(I, 8).Value
            Cap = Cells(I, 34).Value
            
            Rem what's and where's your template?
            '.... I have the main template saved in folder A. ..."* the main template,
            'You mean the (1) .dot or .dotm file?  or (2) just a .doc or .docx file? *"
            'if it is (1) then use the (1)
            'else use the (2)
            
            '(1)
            Set letter = wordApp.Documents.Add(Template:=" your template's path(full name.) here. ie.  the main template' folder A' path + the main template's file name and extension ") 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.add
            
            
            '(2)
            'Set letter = getobject(" your template .doc or .docx file's full name ")
            'or you can use Open method :
            'Set letter = WordApp.Documents.Open(" your template .doc or .docx file's full name ")
            'letter.Windows(1).Visible=True
            'letter.activate
            'letter.application.activate
            
            
            If letter.Bookmarks.Count > 0 Then
                Rem check is the bookmarks all set
                'not implement yet
                
            Else
                MsgBox "Please use the correct Template!", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            wordApp.ScreenUpdating = False

            With letter.Bookmarks
                .Item("SyndNo").Range.Text = SyndNo
'                .Item("Address1").Range.Text = Address1 'why your code lost this one?
                .Item("CEO").Range.Text = CEO
                .Item("Recipient").Range.Text = Recipient
                .Item("Cap").Range.Text = Cap
                
            End With
        End With
        
        
        Rem where and what's your copy from the file
        'You have to assign the value of dSourceFullname to get the document you want to copy
        'this is Where you need to input these file paths (full name of them). ie. the files in folder B
        'how to set the value is up to you (you didn't mention this)
        dSourceFullname = " the full name of the copy-from file "
        
        Set dSource = GetObject(dSourceFullname)
        
        'copy the content of dSource to letter
        letter.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        letter.Range.InsertAfter dSource.Content.Text
        
        wordApp.ScreenUpdating = True
        wordApp.ScreenRefresh
        
        'close the copy-from file
        dSource.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
        
        
        'save letter    'if this your naming rule for Word's files and this is the format you want to (wdFormatXMLDocument)
        '"saved in folder C. " You have to set the correct value to filenameDoc ( full name of the file in C folder.)
        '"File path where letter is saved" have to be replaced
        filenameDoc = "File path where letter is saved" & SyndNo & "_Draft Letter.docx"
        letter.SaveAs2 filenameDoc, wdFormatXMLDocument
        letter.Close 'wdSaveChanges
        
    Next I

    Rem Remember to restore the settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Rem Release Memory and end the procedure
    Set letter = Nothing: Set rng = Nothing: Set dSource = Nothing
    wordApp.Quit
    Set wordApp = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing


    Sheets("Details").Select
    MsgBox "Letters have been produced."
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your code I feel like the answer is very close!

Comment: I still cannot seem to copy over the contents from one document to the other. I have an answer to some of your questions. I have the main template saved in folder A. This is where all my bookmark locations are saved. This will need to be populated with those bookmarks and saved in folder C. I then need the contents of one of the files in folder B copied over to the new file saved in folder C. The naming convention for folder B and C will always be SyndNo followed by a different name. The SyndNo will be different for each file which is why I need it to loop through a list in excel.

Comment: You also mentioned "Where are my word files". Where do I need to input these file paths?

Comment: @SeanHarrison *".... I have the main template saved in folder A. ..."* the main template, You mean the .dot or .dotm file?  or just a .doc or .docx file? *"...Where do I need to input these file paths?..."* , I've updated my code you can see how to do it appropriately to you.